# setup server for django application in Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard

Tags: python, django, nginx, webserver, windows-server-2012-r2

I **must** setup a network computer (running **Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard**) as a production server for django applications, real quick. This is what I've already done:

1. Installed Python 3.7.4 (64 bits version)
2. Installed nginx 1.17.4
3. Installed virtualenv
4. Created a virtual environment for hosting my application
5. Have my django project ready and running ok with "manage.py runserver"

Where do I go from here? I'm sorry, but I couldn't find instructions simple and atraightforward enough for me so far.

I could use IIS or Apache as well, but only if it's simpler than nginx.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is a way to publish a django app without any other framework like apache ngix and others.

1. open windows server 2012's server management app
2. create a TCP port(the port depends on which you want to use. I am using 1234)
3. after these run manage.py with this code (python manage.py runserver server's ip adress:port you opened) and press enter
4. that's it. this way will run your django app on your ip and port adress but you cannot access django app with a domain
   if you find an other way please share me

Comment: Hi, thank you. Actually, I needed to make it available with a domain. So I went with [these instructions](https://medium.com/@Jonny_Waffles/deploy-django-on-iis-def658beae92) and it worked.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, actually i tried IIS also but it didn't work me. May i ask your python's version? @VBobCat

Comment: I've been updating, but it worked for me since version 3.6

Comment: As I tought i am using a recent version(3.7) probably that's why it didn't work for me. Thank you for answer

Comment: No, I mean , it has been working since version 3.6 but it worked also with the more recent ones

Comment: @VBobCat Oh sorry, i didn't get it at first glance but okey then i will try it. Thank you